# Windows 10 update to 1511 installation fails

Tags: windows-10, windows-update, windows-10-v1511

I'm having problems updating to the Windows 10 November Update (1511) with an error saying "Something Happened"

[image]

I've tried to update using

- Windows Update
- [Media Creation Tool](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/software-download/windows10)
- [Tech Bench ISO](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/software-download/techbench)

I've also

- Run the Windows Disk Cleanup Tool
- Run the [Windows Update troubleshooter](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-10/windows-update-troubleshooter)

  This one always finds two errors which it says that it fixed:

  - Potential error in Windows Update database were was discovered: 0x80070490
  - Windows Update components must be repared
- Executed `sfc /scannow` in an elevated command prompt
- Executed `dism /online /cleanup-image /restorehealth` with an ISO as source
- Renamed the `C:\Windows\SoftwareDistribution\Download` folder

---

**What else can I try?**

Comment: what happens if you mount the downloaded ISO run setup.exe and select upgrade?

Comment: @magicandre1981 The installation always stops and closes at ~20% and then shows the box in the image above

Comment: @Oskar: Have you tried with "get updates" *unticked*?

Comment: @TomWijsman Yes, no difference

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something is *extra* or *corrupt* in your installation that isn't in others; so, you'll want to trim down:

1. Uninstall your antivirus, firewall and other possibly intervening software; disabling isn't enough.
2. Disable everything that doesn't need to start in `msconfig` to avoid further intervening trouble.
3. Run `dism /online /cleanup-image /restorehealth` to fix your Windows packages' health
4. Consult the Event Viewer and log files (WindowsUpdate.log, setupact.log, setuperr.log, ...)
5. Try installing again whilst using [Process Monitor](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/processmonitor.aspx) such that you can investigate or export a report about what is really happening before it gives the message box; it'll help figure out the last log it has written too, as well as which files and service entries were accessed last.
6. Beyond this point you could create a new user and uninstall as much software and drivers as possible; but really, at this point you might as well do a fresh Windows 10 Build 1511 install.

Comment: Went with the Windows 10 Build 1511 fresh install, couldn't find any other solution