# Windows 10 VM fails to update

Tags: windows-10, windows-update

I have a Windows 10 VM that is failing to install updates. I've tried it repeatedly, and also tried the anniversary update but with no success. I would really like to get it updated without wiping the machine because I have a ton of work tools configured on it already.

I've also tried the steps listed here: [Windows 10 update to 1511 installation fails](https://superuser.com/questions/1083553/windows-10-update-to-1511-installation-fails)

```
C:\WINDOWS\system32>dism /online /cleanup-image /restorehealth

Deployment Image Servicing and Management tool
Version: 10.0.10586.0

Image Version: 10.0.10586.0

[==========================100.0%==========================]

Error: 1009

The configuration registry database is corrupt.

The DISM log file can be found at C:\WINDOWS\Logs\DISM\dism.log
```

Here is the log file results: https://gist.github.com/jocull/c599d85deebf00a993c027dee30d644f

Here are the failing updates:

[image]

And here are my current system details:

[image]

If there are any other relevant details I can provide, I would be happy to. I've dug through the Event Viewer logs, but didn't see anything important. It's very possible I just didn't know where to look.

### Update - tried to install updates from ISO

Updates failed, here is the result:

[image]

Comment: Have you downloaded the Version 1607 ISO, mounted the ISO to the VM, and attempted to install the 1607 upgrade that way?  The simplest way to solve problems like this, with Windows 10, is to upgrade to the current branch.

Comment: It is worth pointing out, this system has not been updated, in over 8 months.  Windows 10 build 10586.164 was released back in Jan/Feb/March 2016.

Comment: @Ramhound Yes, this is a fairly dated VM. What happened originally was I created a copy of it and then pushed that copy forward into insider preview territory. I used it for awhile, but it got quite buggy and I wanted to roll it back. So I've booted the pre-insider VM up again and now I'm trying to make it current, but getting stuck. I'll try the latest ISO and see if that works. Do I need to boot into it or just run it from within Windows?

Comment: You run the installer from within Windows, otherwise if you boot to the ISO, you would install Version 1607 of your current installation instead of performing a upgrade installation which is what would be done if you were being pushed the 1607 update over Windows Update.

Comment: Error 0x800703f1 (wpaevent.mc)= "WPA_AFTERGRACEPERIODACTIVATION_FAILED_EVENT"  
- "You have not activated Windows within the grace period. To activate Windows, contact a customer service representative by telephone."   Does that copy of Windows 10 report as being properly activated?

Comment: Weird! Yes, the "Check if windows is activated" settings panel claims that it is activated. It might be confused because this is a rollback from a copy that was pushed forward to insider previews. I can attempt to re-activate it, though! Good catch!

Comment: @Ramhound Updates from ISO failed :( See result above

Comment: @Ƭᴇcʜιᴇ007 Refreshed my activation key, but everything appears to still be stuck :(

Comment: I decided I didn't have the time to sink into this anymore and I wiped clean to a new Windows 10 VM. After which Microsoft promptly installed Candy Crush and FarmVille 2 for me. What in the hell is going on over there? This is infuriating.